# I have faced a problem with Verilog Multiplier Module

Tags: verilog

Picture given is a module I'd like to express.
[MulCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ0YU.png)

For some reason I had to bring up the Multiplicand or Multiplier from arrays of numbers using wire. ex)wire [3:0] abc = 4'b1111;

But very odd! When I assign specific value of wire abc to "Multiplier", it works well. However if I assign it to "Multiplicand", I see red lines just as in the picture. [redline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIvXd.png)

Any idea what had gone wrong? Thanks

**Code for MulCell**

```
module MulCell(Multiplicand,Multiplier,Sin,Cin,Sout,Cout);
input Multiplicand,Multiplier,Sin,Cin;
output Sout,Cout;
reg Sout,Cout;
wire tmp;

assign tmp=Multiplicand&Multiplier;
always@(tmp) begin
    {Cout,Sout} <= tmp+Sin+Cin;
end
endmodule
```

**Code for testbench_MulCell**

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module testbench_MulCell();
reg Multiplicand,Multiplier,Sin,Cin;
wire Sout,Cout;

MulCell MC(Multiplicand,Multiplier,Sin,Cin,Sout,Cout);
wire [3:0]abc;
assign abc=4'b1111;

initial begin
    Multiplicand=abc[2];
    Multiplier=1'b1;
    Sin=1'b1;
    Cin=1'b1;
    #10 //expecting 11

    Multiplicand=1'b0;
    Multiplier=abc[1];
    Sin=1'b1;
    Cin=1'b1;
    #10 $stop;//expecting 10
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong, but it seems there's a race condition between assigning value to `abc` and running `initial` block. At the moment when initial block started running, the `assign abc =..` isn't executed yet. That's why you get `x`/red_lines in waveform view.

Comment: you are corect. there is a race.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog is an event driven simulator. It means that every 'always...', 'assign' block has inputs and outputs. Inputs in always block is are represented by its sensitivity list. In your case that would be the `tmp` signal. The whole  block will start evaluation if and only if a change of an input is detected.

Also in the module the `initial` is scheduled for execution once during the simulation and is always executed first, before any of the always blocks (except in special cases in system verilog). So, in your case first few statements of the initial block (before first #10) are executed *before* the *assign* statement. So, for the first 10 cycles value of `abc` will be *`4bxxxx*, which explains your red line. For the same reason the values. As a result, values of *multiplicand* and consequently of *MC/tmp,Sout,Cout* will also be 'x'.

At #10 you change the values of the variables, causing always block in MC to re-evaluate with new values. By that time abc is already set to *1111* and all 'x' disappear.

So, efficiently  you simulated only the second set of values but hot the first.
The suggestion is: add a small delay in front of the initial block:

```
initial begin
    #1
    Multiplicand=abc[2];
    Multiplier=1'b1;
    Sin=1'b1;
```

This will delay execution of the statements and the value of 'abc' will be set by this time. You will have a short period (1) of the red line, but you will see results of the values you set.

Another possibility is to set value of abc in the initial block first, but you would need a **reg** variable to do so:

```
reg[3:0] abcSet;
assign abc = abcSet;

initial begin
     abcSet = 4'b1111;
     ...
```

another thing, in your always block you use non-blocking assignment (<=). Do not! This is good for flops and latches but bad for simple combinatorial logic. Use the regular assignment there (=).

```
{Cout,Sout} = tmp+Sin+Cin;
```

Also, this always block will not be avaluated if you just change Sin or Cin and tmp stays the same. You should either add those into the sensitivity list:

```
always @(tmp, Sin, Cin)
```

or use `always @*` instead. Actually it is a good idea to always use this construct instead of regular V95 always blocks. This way you will avoid possible implicit latches in the design (as in your case in respect to missing parts of the sensitivity list).

Also, in general most of the modern designs are synchronous designs and use a clock signal for synchronization. In your case the multpliplier sell shoudl be synchronized as well, you would need to provide a toggling clock signal. In theis case your operation could look like the following:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    {Cout,Sout} <= tmp+Sin+Cin;
```

It makes evaluation happen at positive edge of the `clk` signal, it it is the only member of the sensitivity list. All other signals should set before the clock change.  And yes, it is a `flop` and `<=` is used there.

Comment: Thank you so much for fantastic explanation. I should print this out.